# A good port for my nodejs game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

I am making a nodejs game. I have tried many ports(25565,12100,2754,6112,1337 and other random ports). All of them worked serverside, however clientside they were sometimes blocked by firewalls or (what is my biggest concern) used by something else what increased latency alot. So what I need is a port that is(if possible) mostly open and that got nothing using it that would disturb my game's connection. Any suggestions for good ports?

Comment: The best solution would be to allow the user to select which port he/she wants to use. No matter what port you chose, there is always the possibility that some other application uses it.

Comment: You cant ask the user such a technical question. How is he supposed to know which ports are open or not.

Comment: Well then I'd have to run the server on multiple port and the user would have to think of a port each time they play, what would be hard for many people(like TJHeuvel pointed out). And I can't make it like choose the next port when one fails since usually they can connect, but something disturbs the connection thus making it laggy.

Comment: @ValentinKrummenacher how about latency testing for each port and using the least laggy. That way, the user *never knows about it*.

Comment: Is it impossible to use port 80? It is the port most likely to be open on firewalls. You should be concerned only with the port on the server side, the client should select a free port automatically.

Comment: Port 80 is what webservers use normally isnt it? And I have a webserver running on my server. Also serverside I am having no problems. Its more that the clients somehow get very laggy on some ports while other programs are using em.

Comment: TCP ports are not like wifi frequencies. They are not shared between several streams. Once you establish a connection on a port, other processes cannot establish a new one on the same port (would get "address in use" error). There's no such thing as a "more laggy" and "less laggy" port.

Comment: @ValentinKrummenacher If your webserver is also a Node.js application you could integrate your game server into it, otherwise you can't use port 80 (well you could with some proxying, but that would only add additional latency and complexity). If your game server listens on port 12345 on your server, there is no way for any other program on your server to be using the same port, and it does not matter if anything is using the same-numbered port on the client, since ports don't have to match and the client will just pick a free port to use.

Comment: My webserver is not nodejs, so I guess I cannot integrate it. And since the client apparently chooses a random port I guess changing the port wont affect clientside, would it?

Comment: The client chooses a random port for _its_ side of the connection; it still needs to know which port to use for the _server_-side.

Comment: @lanzz: Well I guess then it was my users internet connection or something and not only the specific port I was using. I guess in this case I will try to find a different way to reduce latency and lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should checkout the study about WebSockets and Firewalls made by the guys at Socket.IO:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Socket.IO-and-firewall-software

Comment: If I got hat article right the port 843 is pretty often available. I guess I will try it and see if it works fine. Thanks in advance.